# Android Gradle project sync failed due to target version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Since a new **API of Android 6.0** is available in SDK Manager a hint was appeared in application level build.gradle file to update

FROM

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
```

TO

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

I haven't downloaded new update from sdk manager for Android 6(API 23) yet but still changed the following details as shown below,

**BEFORE**

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
targetSdkVersion 22
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
```

**AFTER**

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    targetSdkVersion 23
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

As I haven't downloaded new API 6.0 yet, following error occurred

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: C:\Users\DRONE\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

So now again I changed the setting in application level build.gradle file as what it was before, but the error is not being resolved.
Same error is occurring.

How do I solve this now?

Comment: Did you update your SDK Manager downloading the API23?

Comment: No but build.gradle file is pointing to API 22

Comment: Maybe download the API 23 but use API 22 (if you need 22).

Comment: try to use gradle clean

Comment: I faced this error ever I has API 23 installed and project was running fine but When I tried to update some more components and canceled in between downloading then SDK Manager changed the API 23 SDK as Not Installed, So I just installed again and surprisingly it did not downloaded again. Just unzipped the existing file and installed it instantly.

Comment: If you are using studio must have to update everything include plugins sdk and so on this is the only way to use this IDE

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally it is caused by not having API 23.
After updating the SDK to the newer version, it often rewrites `build.gradle` to the highest API version SDK provided even if you didn't upload it.
The easiest way - download API 23.

Comment: this was a crazy 2h adventure... indeed, you just need this version installed, that's it.. such a pitty. Anyway, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 15):

I think it may caused by you don't have 23 API, Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and check to see if API-23 is installed.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I haven't downloaded API 23 but I do have API 22 and my gradle.built file is pointing to API version 22 not 23.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a "+" for example:
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'

You have also to update your Android Studio APIs (as Kun said).

Comment: I stil tried this out and restarted my PC, am on windows 10. Still can't find target with has-string 'android-23'

Answer (score 1):

Yes as others have mentioned you need to install API-23 through the SDK Manager but it's a long list of downloads and if you don't want to install all of them right away, you can just install the one named "SDK Platform" under API-23