# Error:(12) Error parsing XML: junk after document element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

How to fix this issue?

> Error:(12) Error parsing XML: junk after document element

[image: Screenshot 1]

I'm getting an error here.  How do I fix it?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Please post the relevant code and errors here.

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question so that it meets the guidelines.

Comment: Normally it is caused by not having API 23.Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and check to see if API-23 is installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Gradle project sync failed due to target version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228979/android-gradle-project-sync-failed-due-to-target-version)

Comment: Please post details for XML and Gradle in above question as code not as screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `/>` at the end of your root `LinearLayout` element to `>` to make it a non-self-terminating element.

XML files can have only one root element and there can be no content after the root element is terminated.